# How do I define a new div with a data-role without creating errors?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile

Good afternoon,

I am currently trying to create a Jquery-mobile page that is able to dynamically generate new divs. However, whenever I create a new div that has a data-role, the console will complain that it's not valid.

That is, the following code gives me an error:

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.data-role = "page";   <-- Erroneous Line
```

I've attempted to search extensively, but I unfortunately simply cannot seem to find a solution to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

your `div` variable is a JavaScript object. Object properties cannot be hyphenated, that's why there's an error with your code.

But you don't want to modify the Element object's property anyway, you want to modify the attribute of the HTML tag it represents. This can be accomplished using the `setAttribute` function

Like so,

```
div.setAttribute("data-role","page");
```

[Read More Here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp)